# after/before (Un)Marshal event fires twice and for xml only

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, jax-rs, glassfish-3, moxy

A simple class, that is being marshalled for output:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foobar {
    // ...

    void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) {
        System.out.println("beforeMarshal fired");
    }
}
```

The JAX-RS is also very simple:

```
@GET
public Response getResponse() {
    Foobar fb = new Foobar();
    // ...
    return Response.ok(fb).build();
}
```

The expected output would be "beforeMarshal fired" once, but it fires twice?
Is this normal? I don't think using an extra flag is a good idea ..

```
@XmlTransient
private boolean marshalled;

void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) {
    if (!this.marshalled) {
        System.out.println("beforeMarshal");
        this.marshalled = true;
    }
}
```

Also, when querying the resource for json output, it doesn't fire the marshal event at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There was a bug (see: http://bugs.eclipse.org/412417) in MOXy that would prevent the calling of marshal/unmarshal methods in OSGi environments such as GlassFish.  This is now fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3, 2.4.3, 2.5.1, and 2.6.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build from the following link starting **July 10, 2013**:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

I have not been able to reproduce the issue where the same event is called twice.  If you have a code example that demonstrates this issue please start an email conversation with me through my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html

---

**XML BINDING**

If you are seeing that the `beforeMarshal` method is being called twice instead of once then you are using the reference implementation and not [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider.

***Demo Code***

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foobar.class);
        System.out.println(jc.getClass());

        Foobar foobar = new Foobar();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(foobar, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output - JAXB Reference Implementation***

```
class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
beforeMarshal fired
beforeMarshal fired
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><foobar/>
```

***Output - EclipseLink MOXy***

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
beforeMarshal fired
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foobar/>
```

To enable MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**JSON BINDING**

MOXy uses the same plumbing for XML and JSON binding.  This means that you will see the same event behaviour for both.  If you are not seeing events then a JSON binding provider other than MOXy.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html

Comment: I do have both the `jaxb.properties` file set and the custom Application `<param-value>rest.MyApplication</param-value>` in web.xml. So i think MOXy is my JAXB provider.

Comment: @Imperative - What is the implementation class of the `Marshaller` passed to you in the `beforeMarahal` method?  If it is `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller` then you are using `MOXy`.

Comment: It's `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller`. My goal is to invoke events when processing objects on my JAX-RS server. Your demo works very well, but is it possible to utilize this mechanisms for JAX-RS? I'm asking this, because i can't find any samples on this.

Comment: @Imperative - I am away the next couple of days.  I will dig I to this first thing on Tuesday.